# How can I loop through the rows of a Grid in a TabControl (vb.net)?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, tabcontrol

I have a tab control that has a number of tabs and each tab page has a grid added to it. When I click on Save As button I want the program to loop through the grids on each tab and save the data in an XML-like format.

The file should look something like this:

```
<GridTabPage1>
<Row1> A, B, C ... </Row1>
</GridTabPage1>
```

What I am currently trying but it is not working is:

```
For Each row As DataGridView In TabControl.SelectedTab.Controls(Grid.Rows)
...
Next
```

Could anyone please point me in the right direction?

I hope my explanation of the problem was not confusing. Let me know if you need clarification.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Using xw As New XmlTextWriter("C:\test.xml", System.Text.Encoding.Default)
        xw.Formatting = Formatting.Indented
        xw.WriteStartDocument()
        xw.WriteStartElement("grids")
        For Each tp As TabPage In Me.TabControl1.Controls.OfType(Of TabPage)()
            For Each dgv As DataGridView In tp.Controls.OfType(Of DataGridView)()
                xw.WriteStartElement("DataGrid")
                For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgv.Rows
                    xw.WriteStartElement("row")
                    For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
                        xw.WriteElementString("cell", cell.Value)
                    Next
                    xw.WriteEndElement()
                Next
                xw.WriteEndElement()
            Next
        Next
        xw.WriteEndElement()
        xw.WriteEndDocument()

    End Using
```

Comment: thanks you so much both of you guys. that is exactly what i wanted. thank one and have a good weekend

Comment: and I guess when i want to open the file and populate the grid with that data I could use similar code to achieve this functionality right?

Comment: thank you so much. You my friend are a star and I mean it. Thank you one more time

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
For Each tp As TabPage In TabControl1.TabPages
  For Each dgv As DataGridView In tp.Controls.OfType(Of DataGridView)()

  Next
Next
```

It loops through all of the TabPages and for each TabPage, it will find any DataGridView control(s) that are on that page.